# How to Access a Struct Inside a Struct in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I'm trying to access the variables `string ModelName` and `int Sales` like this `Dealer.Modelo.ModelName` but it's not working. How can I access those variables to fill the the structure?

PD: The compiler says that "Dealer" should have a class type.

```
const int MAXIMODEALERS = 20;
const int MAXIMOMODELOS = 6;
struct Detail
{
    string ModelName;
    int Sales;
};

struct Element
{
        string   CompanyName;
        Detail  Modelo[MAXIMOMODELOS];
};

Element Dealer[MAXIMODEALERS];
```

Comment: Dealer[0].Modelo[0].ModelName

Answer (score 5):

```
Element Dealer[MAXIMODEALERS];
```

declares an array of objects of type `Element`, but :

```
Dealer.Modelo.ModelName = "something";
```

is treating `Dealer` as it would be a single instance of `Element`, neither an array. You need to use an index to access concrete element (same for the `Modelo`):

```
Dealer[SomeIndex].Modelo[OtherIndex].ModelName = "something";
```

Comment: Don't forget Modelo is also an array